# Nifi and Spark Integration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-nifi

I want to create a Spark Session within a Nifi Custom processor written in Scala, so far I can create my spark session on a scala project, but when I add this spark session inside the OnTrigger method of the nifi custom processor, the spark session is never created, is there any way to achieve this? so far I have imported spark-core and spark-sql libraries
any feedback is appreciated

Comment: Please provide sample code and configuration so we can better help you. There are many details missing leaving us with too many potential root causes to discuss.

Comment: So how did you go? I think my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Flow File. Period.

You need Kafka in between Spark Streaming or Spark Structured Streaming. Here is good read btw: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Structured-Streaming-with-NiFi-and-Kafka-using-PySpark/ta-p/245068

Comment: thanks! ok, not with the FlowFile, but still, can is a custom processor able to create a spark session to process the flowfile content and close this session after that?

Comment: I do not think possible from my experience.

Comment: ok thanks, i will let you know in case i achieve this

Comment: Indeed if you do. Would mot make sense if non streaming imho.

Comment: https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/stream_processing_nifi_and_spark this may convince you.